# Iterate between workbooks using INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a summary file where I wish to import the data from cell D11 from some workbooks. For this I try to use INDIRECT to call the workbook O284, where O284 through O296 consists of strings like:

```
 2015-01 (for O284), 2015-02 (for O285 etc)
```

and where O285 is the sheetname, which is consistent for each workbook hence the $$'s.

```
=INDIRECT("'C:\Path\["&O284&"]"&$O$285&"'!$D$11")
```

Running this however does not return a value, but merely a ####. I have all the workbooks opened. I suspect I conduct the INDIRECT snippet wrong, but I can't figure out how. Does anybody have a clue?

Regards,

Btw, is there a way to achieve the same thing as with INDIRECT that work with closed workbooks without using macros? Like a "paste value" or something which you can use in the same way as INDIRECT but that returns a digit, without the formula notation in the cell?

EDIT:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'C:\path\[";O282;"]";$O$283;"'!D11"))
```

works for getting the value "D11" from the workbook O282. When I drag this formula out, the next column will reference to workbook P282. However, it still get cell D11. I want it to get the E11 cell from this workbook, and work like this. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Hmm.. trying to understand, where do you need to use CONCATINATE?

Comment: Pardon me, I'm out of your question, I'm deleting my comments. Showing #### is sometimes because of cell width, that I think you actually know this.

Comment: It was not due to cell width, but your comment actually works. I'm now trying to make it work so that "D11" does not use $$, and instead can be dragged out to E11, F11 etc. Havent gotten it to work yet by simply removing the $$'s or by changing some " '.

Comment: In [Office support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474B3A3A-8A26-4F44-B491-92B6306FA261) it seems you don't need `$$`, but when you make a reference by clicking it add `$$`. But Actually I suggest using `ADDRESS(11,4)` instead of `D11`, this will help you in changing columns ;).

Comment: I add an answer by using `column()` function to change `D` to `E`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'C:\";[@Path];"\[";[@WorkbookName];"]";[@SheetName];"'!";ADDRESS(11;COLUMN() - 11)))
```

I think up code is something that can you want.

- Showing `####` is sometimes because of cell width.