# Replace INDIRECT with INDEX to iterate closed workbooks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Yesterday I started a topic in regards of iterating cells from some workbooks into a new, summary workbook. For this I used INDIRECT function:

[Iterate between workbooks using INDIRECT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962684/iterate-between-workbooks-using-indirect)

However, realizing the backdrafts of INDIRECT I want to achieve the same thing, but by using INDEX, as I've read from forums that INDEX works even when the referenced workbook is closed, wheras INDIRECT does not.

Then, using

```
 =INDEX(CONCATENATE("'C:\Pathtofile\[";O282;"]";$O$283;"'!";ADDRESS(11;KOLUMN()-23));1)
```

Where O282 is the workbook I want to reference (which is referenced in this manner as I will need to iterate some workbooks like the workbook 2015-01 (O282), 2015-02 (P282) etc.) and O283 is the sheet of the corresponding workbook, which in this case is static. I want to import the value of cell D12 in the referenced workbook and worksheet with this, and actually the INDEX does this. ;1 is used to indicate that I only want to return 1 cell. (I believe US excel uses "," instead of ";").

The problem is though that it returns:

```
 'C:\Pathtofile\[2015-01]Data'!$D$11
```

so basically. INDEX references correct, but it returns the path and not the value which is intended.

EDIT:

I've tried:

```
 =INDEX(CONCATENATE("'C:\Pathtofile\[";O282;"]";$O$283;"'!";ADDRESS(11;KOLUMN()-23):ADRESS(12;KOLUMN()-23));1)
```

to get the Array D12:E12, and then reference to the value at the first referenced row, i.e. D12. This hasn't worked though, but it has been a way to avoid the problems associated with INDEX interpreting my input as a mean to return a reference, rather than a value.

Comment: Index works even when the referenced workbook is closed? That's not true. It will just display you the cached value. Should the source workbook get changed, you will not see the changes in the destination until you refresh workbook connections (which is in fact re-opening the referenced file).

Comment: If I understand this correct. The referenced files are updated manually by adding the new monthly data "by hand" by a coworker. The Index function in the destination file will then update automatically? Or do I need to personally open the files for the destination file to update? Do you know of any other function which can do what I sought after?

Comment: The value in the destination file will be updated only if both source and destination files are open. Then if you save the destination file, the new value will be cached and displayed next time you open the file (even if the source file is closed at that moment). If you need to fetch info without having to open the source file, it can be done only via VBA.

Comment: Oh then I totally misunderstood INDEX. But then again, merely open the files once a month must be considered doable as it is so few files to open, so I'll continue with INDEX. As long as I don't need to have them open every time I check the summary file.  
Do you have any idea as to why the formula only returns the path?

Comment: Ok, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX`, in your case, takes two arguments: reference and position. Instead of reference, you specified *address*, so Excel understands it as range with one value in it - which is your address and returns it to you. You should:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(...));1)
```

But as you use the first value in referenced range, you can simply do:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(...))
```

Comment: =INDEX(array,row_num,[column_num]) - this is the array form of the INDEX function. - See more at: http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-excels-index-function-find-data-table#comment-414 is the reference I used for that notation. I'm gonna update the OP for something I've tried to avoid the reference for INDEX as a mean to return a reference, but rather a value.

Comment: Including INDIRECT does not take advantage of cached values, so it will have all the workbooks opened at any time you want to see a value, as I understand? This cannot be, as this file is a summary file which will be used by many people who doesn't have access to all the files I'm referencing to.

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. You can't take advantage of caching with dynamically generated addresses... I will think on another approach.

Comment: Thanks for investing your time. I'm searching very much for a solution as well

Comment: Or is there a way to "copy" cached values? I.e. a formula that takes a "snapshot" of cached values or similar?